# Как преобразовать тему Wordpress для её разработки на Yii2

Tags: wordpress, yii, yii2

Задача в следующем ...

Есть тема для Wordpress: [тыц](https://pixelgrade.com/demos/lens/).

Нужно её разработать на Yii2.

С Wordpress'ом не знаком. В Yii2 новичок. Но проблема не в Yii2, пробела в том, как сграбить вёрстку, CSS, JS и всё сопутствующее с указанной темы. Есть идеи?

Comment: Я вообще склоняюсь к варианту, что проще её самому написать с нуля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получаем верстку, css, js и все сопутствующие:

```
wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc http://site.com
```

И потом используем в своем проекте

P.S. воровать плохо

Comment: Это тестовое задание для меня; чтобы попрактиковаться и проверить как я усвоил Yii. Так что итоговый сайт никуда не пойдёт. А откуда руководитель взял тему, без понятия :). Спасибо за подсказку. В итоге всё равно получаетсся куча зависимостей, которые нужно разбирать, так как даже в `index.html` всего нагенерированного не пойми откуда. Я пойду другим путём: лучше поговорю, чтобы я сверстал сам подобие (так как основное для меня Yii) и функционал по-быстрому и приступил к Back End'у.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov удачи вам в ваших начинаниях :)